# mySQL Как правильно связать таблицу "саму на себя"?

Tags: mysql

```
  ID  |  priceID  |  parentID  |  value  |
------|-----------|------------|---------|
   1  |     1     |            |  0.01   |
   2  |     1     |            |  0.02   |
   3  |     2     |      1     |  0.11   |
   4  |     2     |      1     |  0.12   |
```

Нужно подставить "потомку" все значения "родителя". Вот как я делаю сейчас:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.priceID, 
    IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value) value
FROM 
    some_table t1
    LEFT JOIN some_table t2 on t1.parentID = t2.priceID
WHERE 
    t1.priceID = 2

  priceID  |  value  |
-----------|---------|
     2     |  0.01   |
     2     |  0.02   |
     2     |  0.11   |
     2     |  0.12   |
```

Этот способ рабочий, но на самом деле полей у меня довольно много, и для каждого писать IFNULL() не хочется. Есть ли другой способ решить мою задачу? Если это существенно - я хочу сделать из этого запроса Views, что наверняка накладывает свои ограничения (например, я уже знаю что нужно избегать вложенных запросов при составлении запросов для views). Тот вариант решения, который я упомянул выше, ведет себя во вьюсе очень медленно.

Comment: Придется писать для каждого IFNULL()

Comment: @toxxxa Можно попробовать select priceID, value from some_table where priceID in(select parentID from some_table where priceID=2 and parentID is not null)
union
select parentID. value from some_table where priceID=2 and parentID is null  Не везде применимо и не знаю будет ли быстрее

Comment: @Mike на самом деле, можно еще проще без `union`: `select priceID, value from some_table where priceID in (2, (select parentID from some_table where priceID=2))`, но  views из этого не сделаешь (вложенный запрос, еще и с условием).

Comment: @toxxxa Вообще для MySQL сказано, что в view нельзя использовать подзапросы только в части `FROM` основного запроса. так что в `WHERE` скорее всего можно, проверьте.

Comment: @toxxxa Хотя да, вы значение `2` в такую view никак не передадите. Тогда похоже что в вопросе единственное решение